# Backbone View Event not firing difference

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I am a backbone newbie and I am trying to develop a Todo like App.

I have a Main view which is a list view and it has subviews. - the subview content can be edited on double click and it would get saved when the enter key is pressed. - very similar to todo example given in backbone github code.

```
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",    
    events: {
        "dblclick"              : "show_edit_view",
        "blur .element"         : "close_edit_view",
        "keypress .element"     : "save_edit_view",
        "click button.remove"   : "remove_question"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();             
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    render: function(){        
        this.$el.html(_.template($("#sub_view_template").html(),this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    show_edit_view: function() {
        this.$el.find("div.view").addClass("no_show");
        this.$el.find("input").removeClass("no_show");
    },
    close_edit_view: function(){
        this.$el.find("div.view").removeClass("no_show");
        this.$el.find("input").addClass("no_show");
    },
    save_edit_view: function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {            
            this.model.save({name: e.currentTarget.value});
            this.close_edit_view();
        }
    }
});
```

And the template for this is

```
<script id="sub_view_template" type="text/x-template">
   <div class="view"><%= name %></div>
   <input class="element no_show" value="<%= name %>" type="text" /> <button class="remove">Remove</button>
</script>
```

This one works fine, the model is updated in the view and the update post request is sent to the server.

But, when I change the initialization and save_edit_view functions, only the first change event is fired and not the change events.

```
initialize: function(){
    this.render();             
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    this.input = this.$("input.element");
},
save_edit_view: function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {            
        this.model.save({name: $(this.input).val()});
        this.close_edit_view();
    }
}
```

I was wondering what could the problem be?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: How many times do you call `render`?

Comment: don't call `.render()` function inside the `.initialize()` method. render is supposed to be called outside the view, and just instantiating on view should not mean rendering.

Comment: @alexanderb Because the subview is not assigned to any existing element - I thought it would be better to call render in initialize function. - I guess, I can avoid writing an object for it. that was my intention. But, for those views which are bound to an existing element in the dom, I always call render separately.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, for the subview render is only called in the initialize function.

Comment: I asked because `this.$el.html(...)` replaces everything inside the view's `el` and that would leave your `this.input` referencing something that is no longer on the page if `render` was called again. The way around that problem would be to set up the cached `this.input` inside `render` after `this.$el.html(...)` was called.

Comment: @muistooshort - Thanks, that works! So I guess, I have to write all the elements reference in the render() , setting the same in initialize is not a good idea it seems.

Comment: Right, `el`'s content generally changes inside `render` so anything that references the content of `el` should also go inside `render`. Or don't bother caching the references at all, it is rarely worth the trouble if you use `this.$()` to properly localize your searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are referring to only one object. This means when you make the assignment:

`this.input = this.$('input.element');  // match the current elements`.

You are only getting the value from that exact object. After the first `change`, `this.input` is not the same object that contains your new value, and fails to `save` the model with a new value.

A demonstration that may help:

```
console.log(this.$('input.element') != this.$('input.element')); // true
```

This is why the following would work:

```
save_edit_view: function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {            
    this.model.save({name: this.$('input.element').val()});
    this.close_edit_view();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks fbynite! This was exactly what I was looking for. Of course it worked, but, I wonder, in the ToDo example of Backbone, they used the same method setting up this.some_variable - but, in that App, I was unable to see that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `this.$("input.element");` refers to the first item from the list.
And when you first time change model value with the value from the first item it works. But second time it doesn't works because the value of the first item still the same.
That is why you have to get input value from the event - `e.currentTarget.value`

Comment: Well, this.$("input.element") is an element in every subview which is inside the mainview. I wonder is it a good practice to access the value from the event?

Comment: Yes, this is a good practice. You bind events in the scope of the view. When some event fires you already have an element in the event. So you shouldn't look for it in the DOM once again - it's a redundant operation.